# Поведение сессий PHP

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Не могу разобраться временем жизни сессии.
есть две странички:

a.php:

```
<?
  session_start();
  if(empty($_SESSION['test'])){
    header('Location: v.php?from=ab');
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <style>
        ...     
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>        
    <div class="q1" onClick='location.href="b.php"'></div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

b.php:

```
<?
  session_start();
  if(empty($_SESSION['test'])){
    header('Location: v.php?from=ab');
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        ...     
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>        
    <div class="q1" onClick='location.href="a.php"'></div>          
  </body>
</html>
```

и одна v.php:

```
<?
  session_start();
  if(empty($_GET['from'])){
    $_SESSION['test']="Good";
    $a='start S';
  }else{
    $a='NO start S';
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        ...
    </style>
</head>
  <body>        
     <div class="q1" onClick='location.href="a.php"'><?echo $a;?></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

В `php.ini` настройки по умолчанию. Суть проблемы в том, что, записав сессию в `a.php`, жду полчаса жму, на ссылку перехода на `b.php` и меня не перекидывает на страницу `v.php`. 1440 секунды прошло, по идее сессия должна была удалиться.

К примеру, в phpmyadmin когда проходят эти 1440 секунды и куда либо нажимаю, он мне дает понять что сессия завершена. Как реализовать такое поведение, что я не так делаю, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: я вижу phpmyadmin - значит ли это, что сессия хранится в БД?

Comment: Нет, это просто для примера той реализации сессий, которую хотелось бы

Comment: Проверка на сервере,т.е. 
if(сколько_живет_сессия>время_жизни_сессии) session_destroy();

Comment: а как можно узнать сколько живет сессия? 
но почему она по прошествии 1440 по сути продолжает жить, и тогда какой смысл имеет session.gc_maxlifetime, точнее даже, почему уборщик мусора ее не убирает?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ini-get.php
Это не java, уборщика мусора здесь нет. Значит в коде что-то не то, можете выложить код, как он есть?

Comment: Выложил.  По идее через пол часа если я нажму на div со страницы a.php, меня должно перекинуть на v.php, но я спокойно перехожу на b.php

Comment: @AimX что это за жёсткий кастыль?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Углубившись в проблему выяснил, у php есть уборщик, но работает он по дефолту, относительно, т.е. шанс его вызова 1/1000. При большом количестве обновлений страницы (у сайта много посетителей) он в какой-то мере приносит стабильность. В осознании помогла эта статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/171151/. В итоге придумал свой "велосипед". А именно, время жизни сессии устанавливаю так, `ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", [N]);` где N время жизни сессии в секундах. Теперь что бы на 100% выполнялось это условие в переменную записываю время старта сессии:

```
$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT[N]S'));
$_SESSION['sessionLife']=(float)$date->format('YmdHis');
```

И для проверки этого условия в каждый php файл в самом его начале подключаю (`include 'ca.php';`) файл проверки ca.php:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['sessionLife']<=(float)date('YmdHis') or empty($_SESSION['sessionLife'])){
    if($front===true){//если подключен к индексной странице
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();          
        header('Location: v.php');
        exit();
    } else {//если подключен к файлу обработчику запросов
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        exit('{"status":"logout"}');
    }
}else{
    $date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $date->add(new DateInterval('PT[N]S'));
    $_SESSION['sessionLife']=(float)$date->format('YmdHis');
}
```

Таким образом поведение сессий полностью предсказуемо, и при превышении лимита времени жизни сессии, она уничтожится и перекинет на стартовую страницу или сообщит о том что время ее жизни истекло.
Надеюсь это кому нибудь поможет или пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

Для вашего случая надо сделать так:

```
session_start(
   array(
     'cookie_lifetime' => 1440 ,
   )
)
```

Все настройки здесь: http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php